# How to share visualizations for public access in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5, xpack

How can I share dashboards and visualizations using a share link and block access to the Kibana (5.1.1) management panel?
When I use X-pack for security then all users have to type login and password to access charts. 
I would just share charts with people nothing more.

Comment: I think, there might be a solution with usage of proxy.